# Tell if google sheet call is done

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that can be updated from a menu item. The last thing I do is alerting the user that the import is done. As it's asynchronous, the API calls has been made but that doesn't mean it's actually done.

As seen below, "Import done" message appear and the user starts using the sheet, but suddenly everything moves as the data is being sorted.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Import').addItem('Import', 'importFunction').addToUi();
}

function importFunction() {
  ... code updating sheet ...
  sheet.sort(1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Import done');
}
```

Is there a way so see if sheet-api calls are still running? Or a better way to inform the user when they can continue using the sheet?

Comment: You might try a `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after the sort.

Comment: Also try `if(response){SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Import done');}`

Comment: If you ran this from a sideBar you might be able to use withSuccessHandler to get a call back and then generate the alert clientside. [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) I like using the sidebar if I'm using a function a lot because it takes less key strokes and I'm lazy in that regard.